# How to auto update github action runner

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I'm looking for a way to auto update my local github action runner.

This is still in beta but work fine and for every update my CI/CD is not running without any notification.

Comment: need tag `github-actions-runners` thanks for someone with enought reputation to add it.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto update"?

Comment: @profy I've suggested an edit.

Comment: auto update means do automatic update of runner binarie code when new one is available. For now it should be run manually for every github update.

Answer (score 0):

You now (July 2020) can try the [new Dependabot](https://github.blog/2020-06-25-dependabot-now-updates-your-actions-workflows/), described by [Alex Mullans](https://github.com/infin8x) :

> ### Dependabot now updates your Actions workflows

> GitHub Actions makes it easy to automate all your software workflows, from continuous integration and delivery to issue triage and more.
> Whether you want to build a container, deploy a web service, or automate welcoming new users to your open source projects—there’s an action for that.
>
> Actions can be frequently updated with bug fixes and new features that might make your build faster, more reliable, and safer.
>
> To take advantage of updates to actions, you previously had to update your Actions workflow file manually. This led to some workflows using outdated versions of actions.
>
> **Now, Dependabot can keep the actions used in your workflow files updated automatically!**
> Dependabot version updates will periodically check your workflow files and the Actions they use and see if new versions are available. If they are, Dependabot will send you a pull request that updates your workflow file to use the new version.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/bulk-actions-checkout.png?resize=1024%2C596?w=1024]
>
> Dependabot creates pull requests that update the action to the latest released tag (e.g., `v2`), regardless of if you’re currently on a release tag, a pre-release tag, or a specific hash.
>
> Dependabot version updates are fully configurable: you can control how often and when your workflow files are checked, who should be assigned to review the PR, and more.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/dependabot-yml.png?resize=1024%2C439?w=1024]
>
> To enable Dependabot version updates for GitHub Actions, check a `dependabot.yml` configuration file into your repository.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Actions Runner](https://github.com/actions/runner) should update itself automatically unless you passed the `--disableupdate` command line parameter to `config.sh`.

`--disableupdate` was added January 2022 https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/1558.

The code to automatically update the agent seems to have always been there. At least since the [first commit](https://github.com/actions/runner/blame/2f261f2c31a347977adf955ae8ad243b09569739/src/Runner.Listener/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs) to the open source repository.